# Photoshop - Video Timeline Timecode units confusion

Tags: adobe-photoshop, video

When a Video Timeline is created in Photoshop, there are 2 options for viewing time units:

- a Frame Number mode (which is pretty self-explanatory), and
- the Timecode mode, which I don't understand.

There are 2 kinds of suffixes there : `-f` and `-s`, at first, I thought that the `-s` suffix is  meant to mark seconds, but it's not the case. The `-s` suffixes appear only when I open a video file like `.avi` in Photoshop but the `-s` units are much longer than 1 second, the -`f` ones appear when I create a Timeline within a standard Ps document.

What's the difference between them, and generally what's the concept behind such an unintuitive time units for video in Photoshop?

Edit: A screenshot with `-s` units:

[image]

Eidt2: There are `-m` suffixes as well (movie duration was about 1h 30 mins, so the suffixes mean probably seconds and minutes, taking into account bigger units in front)

[image]

Comment: Cold you please add a screenshot of your timeline panel? I don't see any -s suffixes on mine

Comment: Interesting.. I can find no information on this, nor can I get my version to show an -s in any way. I only see the -f (avi, mp4 both tested). I've tried just about every setting including a smart video layer... always see the -f.

Comment: yes, I also can't make my timeline to show -s even if I open videos

Comment: ah! I see -s if I compress timeline and they are seconds. I guess the question is: what do you mean by "these units are longer than 1 second"? Could it be that your video isn't cached so it plays in slower speed?

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy How are you "compressing the timeline" I've tried.. still no -s.

Comment: Ahh.. with the addition of the edit, I wonder if it uses -f to a limit, then switches to -s or -m --- Indeed.. If I open a 20Min video I see the -s

Comment: exactly: https://imgur.com/a/ly7r5Xy

Comment: Okay.. Mine doesn't dynamically toggle like that.. but I am using CC2017 at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, not sure what would be 'intuitive time units' but the units PS uses are common (at least between Adobe apps). Each second consists of N-number of frames, say, 25 like on your screenshots. So when your timeline is zoomed in you have

- Frame 0 is 0:0f
- frame 20 is 0:20f
- frame 30 is 1:05f

etc. When timeline is compressed, seconds start to appear, then minutes — hence is -s and -m suffixes. The reason why the seconds didn't feel like seconds could've been because the video wasn't playing in real framerate: notice the value in the bottom of the panel: it shows the actual framerate. Here I'm playing a 4k video in Photoshop, not the best idea:

[image]